# error: Error: While resolving module `@icons/circleFlower`, the Haste package `@icons` was found. However the module `circleFlower` could not be found

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

**error: Error: While resolving module `@icons/circleFlower`, the Haste package `@icons` was found. However the module `circleFlower` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:**

- `D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\src\Assets\icons\circleFlower(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
- `D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\src\Assets\icons\circleFlower\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  at resolveHasteName (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:198:9)
  at Object.resolve (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:68:20)
  at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:126:31)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
  at Object.resolve (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:170:21)
  at resolveDependencies (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:466:33)
  at processModule (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:232:31)
  at async addDependency (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:361:18)
  at async Promise.all (index 3)
  at async processModule (D:\niraj\react_native\khoj_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\graphOperations.js:279:3)

Comment: have you check if the `circleFlower` is there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jted95 I checked but there is only "import CircleFlower from '@icons/circleFlower' "